# Making new column containing elements of other column

Tags: r

I am trying to make new columns in a data frame that contain elements of one original column and have tried through a variety of ways using sapplyc and unnesting but have not gotten the right results. The column of interest looks like: `df<-data_frame(file=c('U2_pN_Len', 'MM_pND_con', 'COS_CTL'))`
and I want to separate the parts around in-between the _ into their own columns. I tried by making a reference data frame: `df2<-data_frame(cell=c('U2', 'MM', 'COS'), insert=c('pND', 'pN', 'pGFP'), trt=c('Len', 'con', 'CTL'))` and was thinking of using an if command where if an aspect of the original data frame matched some an aspect of each column of df2 then it would print that match, ie I want my final data frame to look like:

```
out<-data_frame(file=c('U2_pN_Len', 'MM_pND_con', 'COS_CTL'), cell=c('U2', 'MM', 'COS'), insert=c('pND', 'pN', 'pGFP'), trt=c('Len', 'con', 'CTL'))
```

Anyone have any advice on how to do this using any command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this approach, each column from df2 becomes a set of terms to check against within `str_extract`.  Depending on how large the actual lists are in your data set, this might become unwieldy.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df<-tibble(file=c('U2_pN_Len', 'MM_pND_con', 'COS_CTL'))
df2<-tibble(cell=c('U2', 'MM', 'COS'), insert=c('pND', 'pN', 'pGFP'), trt=c('Len', 'con', 'CTL'))

cell = str_c(df2$cell, collapse = "|")
insert = str_c(df2$insert, collapse = "|")
trt = str_c(df2$trt, collapse = "|")


df %>%
  mutate(cell = str_extract(file, cell),
         insert = str_extract(file, insert),
         trt = str_extract(file, trt))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   file       cell  insert trt  
#>   <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 U2_pN_Len  U2    pN     Len  
#> 2 MM_pND_con MM    pND    con  
#> 3 COS_CTL    COS   <NA>   CTL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I did try this the issue is that each file name doesn't follow the same pattern, ie I would want CTL to be in the 3rd column as it is under the trt category rather than the insert category so these don't exactly align.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I misunderstood how the output columns were derived. I've edited my answer.